# about "data merge" in SAS

Tags: sas

I am studying data merge in SAS, and find the following example

```
data newdata;
merge yourdata (in=a) otherdata (in=b);
by permno date;
```

I do not know what do "(in=a)" and "(in=b)" mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yourdata(in=a)` creates a flag variable in the program data vector called 'a' that contains 1 if the record is from yourdata and 0 if it isn't. You can then use these variables to perform conditional operations based on the source of the record.

It might be easier to understand if you saw

```
data newdata;
merge yourdata(in=ThisRecordIsFromYourData) otherdata(in=ThisRecordIsFromOtherData);
by permno date;
run;
```

Suppose that records from yourdata needed to be manipulated in this step, but not those from otherdata, you could then do something like

```
data newdata;
merge yourdata(in=ThisRecordIsFromYourData) otherdata(in=ThisRecordIsFromOtherData);
by permno date;
if ThisRecordIsFromYourData then do;
  * some operation here for yourdata records only ;
end;
run;
```

An obvious use for these variables is to control what kind of 'merge' will occur, using `if` statements. For example, `if ThisRecordIsFromYourData and ThisRecordIsFromOtherData;` will make SAS only include rows that match on the by variables from both input data sets (like an inner join).

Comment: It should also be noted that these flag variables do not get kept in the data set being created.  If you want to keep them I normally created additional variables like this: a1=a;b1=b; and then refer to a1 and b1 in the output dataset.